# TSXでリストを動的に作るには

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

動的に配列を作り、状況に応じてその配列の個数が変動します。
その配列の要素から必要な要素を取り出してHTMLのでリストとして表示するにはどうしたら良いでしょう？
書き方はTypeScriptを用いて、TSXで書いています。以下、イメージです：

```
const sample (index: number) => {
  const sampleList: number[] = [];
  for (let item of data[index]) { // <- データの要素数はそのindexごとに毎回違うため、配列に入る個数も変わる。
     sampleList.push(item);
  }

  return (
    <div>
     ...
     <ul>
       ...ここにsampleListに入っている要素の数だけリストを作りたい。 
     </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

どなたか良い方法ご存知ないですか？

Comment: 英語ですが参考になるかと思います: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22876978/5989200

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nekketsuuuさんの参考リンク先にもありますが、mapを使うのが一般的です。

```js
const sample = () => {
  const sampleList = [0, 3, 5]
  return (
    <div>
     <ul>
       {sampleList.map(num=> <li>{num}</li>)}
     </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(sample(), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考になりました。確かにmapを使うのが一番分かりやすく簡単な方法に見えます。